# Can you prove this three-way linear map composition?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, proof-writing

OK, this was an example that my prof gave when talking about surjective, injective and bijective functions. I also am curious if I am approaching this the right way. (Everyone here has been a really big help in pointing out to me where I am messing up).

It comes after one remark he made: the composition of two bijective (linear) maps are bijective.

So the statement: let $f$ be a function from $A \rightarrow \ B$ and $g$ be a function from $A \rightarrow\ C$.

Assume $f$ is surjective.

$\exists$ a function $h:B\rightarrow C$ such that $h\circ f = g \iff \forall x,y \in A, \ f(x) = f(y)$ implies $g(x) = g(y)$

OK. I approached this as follows: given that if $f$ and $g$ are both surjective, $g \circ f$ will be surjective also. It is also true that if $g \circ f$ is surjective, $g$ is surjective.

Now, the only way $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $g(x) = g(y)$ is if g is surjective as well. Is this the case? I am trying to be sure I understand this.

Meanwhile the statement says that there has to be a function h that when applied to f maps to g. But only if the surjectivity of f implies the surjectivity of g.

But that is about as far as I got. And I don't even know if I understood the premise correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really quite simple.  If $f(x) = f(y)$, then $(h(f(x)) = (h(f(y))$, so $g(x) = g(y)$.
On the other hand, suppose $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $g(x) = g(y)$.  For any $x$, 
you want $h(f(x)) = g(x)$.  So just define $h$ on the range of $f$
by $h(t) = g(x)$ where $t = f(x)$.  This is unambiguous because if $t = f(x) = f(y)$, $g(x) = g(y)$.  And on the complement of the range of $f$, define $h$ as you wish.

There is no need for any surjectivity here.  And $f(x) = f(y)$ implying $g(x) = g(y)$ has nothing to do with whether $f$ or $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Ah, my prof was midirecting! Clever! Thanks.

By the way, if I understand you right, the reason your proof works is because you're only trying to show that there is some h that works, right? Not that there is only one or whatever, just that someplace you can have such a function.

Comment: ALso, what if I change the initial statement so that g is a function $B\rightarrow C$? Does that alter things?

Comment: If $g: B \to C$, $g = h \circ f$ doesn't make sense, because $f$ is defined on $A$, not on $B$.